# Reactjs - sort product array based on date

Tags: reactjs

I want to sort date from the product array (date is one of the field in product). Please suggest me. I am using ReactJS.

Please find the code that am using.

```
render() {

          let sortedDate = this.state.item.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(new Date(a.expected_ship_date("/").reverse().join("-"))) - Date.parse(new Date(b.expected_ship_date("/").reverse().join("-"))));
          let sortedDate1 = this.state.item.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.expected_ship_date) - new Date(b.expected_ship_date));

        return (
            <tr>
                <td><input name="line_number" type="text" value={ this.state.item.line_number } disabled={ this.props.mode }  className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange }/> </td>
                <td><input name="requested_ship_date" type="date" value={ this.state.item.expected_ship_date } disabled={ this.props.mode }  className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange }  /></td>

                <td>{sortedDate.map( (c, i) => <div>{c.expected_ship_date}</div>)}</td>
            </tr>

        );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `slice()` the array first, e.g. `this.state.item.slice().sort(...)`, otherwise very bad things will start happening.

Comment: while sort date am getting this error: The specified value "[object Object]" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".   Please find the code :::::     for( var i=0;i < lines.length;i++)
   {
    for( var j=i+1; j< lines.length; j++)
     {
      
      if(lines[i].expected_ship_date < lines[j].expected_ship_date) {
      temp = lines[i].expected_ship_date;
      lines[i].expected_ship_date=lines[j].expected_ship_date;
      lines[j].expected_ship_date=temp;
      }
     }
   }
  
  this.state.item.order_ship_date=lines[0].expected_ship_date;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting you need to convert the date to `epoch` date, and then try to sort.
I suggest you should use `moment` to convert the date to `epoch`

Installation :

```
npm install --save moment
```

Code:

```
import moment from 'moment'

let sortedDate = this.state.item.sort((a, b) => moment(a.expected_ship_date).valueOf() - moment(b.expected_ship_date).valueOf());
```

Comment: while console.log(sortedDate), its printing [object object]. am not getting the actual results. Please suggest.

Comment: Post the result `console.log(this.state.item)`

Comment: Actually, i have to get the latest date after i deleting a product from the table.

 removeLine(id) {
  var item = this.state.item;
  var lines = item.order_items;
 
  var sum=0;
  var total;
  var i = null;
  var count = 0 
  var temp = null;
  for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
   if (lines[j].id == id) {
    i=j;
   }
   
   }
   
  lines.splice(i, 1);
  let sortedDate = lines.sort((a, b) => moment(a.expected_ship_date).valueOf() - moment(b.expected_ship_date).valueOf());
  console.log("Final date:::::"+lines);
  this.setState({ item: item });
 }

Comment: I think JavaScript sort function doesn't return anything. It sort the object itself. Don't require to store in other object.